# Run emacs GUI from emacsclient

Tags: emacsclient

I am running emacs 25.1.

I have emacs server starting as a daemon on startup and I can open an emacs terminal session with the following alias:

```
alias em="emacsclient -t"
```

How can I start the emacs gui in a similar fashion?

Comment: See [MJ Wall's scripts](http://mjwall.com/blog/2013/10/04/how-i-use-emacs/) on using `emacsclient`.

Answer (score 12):

If "start emacs gui in a similar fashion" is hoping to create a gui frame backed by the same daemon, then

```
alias ec="emacsclient --create-frame"
```

will instantiate another emacs frame backed by the same daemon. `--create-frame` can also be abbreviated with `-c`. `-t` or `-nw` or `--tty` are requesting the default for emacsclient which is to open another frame in a tty instead of a gui frame.

See the gnu [emacsclient commandline options](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/emacsclient-Options.html#emacsclient-Options) for more details.

Comment: You could include a link to the doc https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/emacsclient-Options.html#emacsclient-Options

Answer (score 3):

For me on ubuntu 16.04,
after started emacs server
edit your `/usr/share/applications/emacs24.desktop` like this

```
TryExec=/usr/bin/emacsclient -c                                                                                                                                          
Exec=/usr/bin/emacsclient -c %F
```

Answer (score 2):

My solution:

```
alias ecw="emacsclient --c"
```

and use `ecw` to start emacs in GUI.

Answer (score 1):

For fish shell, this works for me:

```
function ec
    emacsclient --create-frame $argv &
end
```